# Why is Batch Build disabled in Visual Studio for projects that use TFS?

Tags: visual-studio

In both VS 2008 and 2010 I either don't see it or it is disabled, but only when the project is under TFS source control. For normwl projects it works just fine.

Comment: what do you mean with "batch build"? building from a batch file?

Answer (score 4):

It's showing up for me in Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Under `Build -> Batch Build`, just as the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx) says. Is that where you're looking?

Comment: Yes. It looks like it only disappears when I have a TFS project open. If I pick one without source control, it appears right where you said it would. Any gueses as to why?

Comment: That's strange. I don't work with many TFS projects, other than those on CodePlex, so I'm afraid I can't think of a reason off the top of my head. Seems I can't find anything on Google about it, either. Sorry. :(